# How to specify link speed while ordering VSI

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using createObject method of  VirtualGuestService for creating the VSI

I am setting the port speed in the template as 1 Gb but it is always created with 10 Mb.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the port speed in megabits in the template, It means that 1Gb will be 1000 megabits.

Try using the following template:

```
{
    "parameters": [
        {
            "hostname": "test",
            "domain": "test.local",
            "datacenter": {
                "name": "dal13"
                },
            "hourlyBillingFlag": "true",
            "operatingSystemReferenceCode": "CENTOS_7_64",
            "networkComponents": [
                     {
                         "maxSpeed": 1000
                     }
                  ],
            "privateNetworkOnlyFlag": "true",
            "supplementalCreateObjectOptions": {
                         "flavorKeyName": "AC1_8X60X25"
           }
        }
    ]
}
```

Reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject/

To get the available port speeds you can use the below rest api call:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions
```

Search the port speeds options by "networkComponents".

You will get a response like this example:

```
"networkComponents": [
          {
            "itemPrice": {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                "recurringFee": "0",
                "dedicatedHostInstanceFlag": true,
                "item": {
                    "description": "1 Gbps Public & Private Network Uplinks (Dedicated Host)"
                }
            },
            "template": {
                "id": null,
                "networkComponents": [
                    {
                        "maxSpeed": 1000
                    }
                ],
                "privateNetworkOnlyFlag": false
            }
        },        
]
```